# Check for mobile number CF7

Tags: php, regex

I have a ContactForm7 form which submits data to a CRM. All works fine but now I need to differentiate between mobile and landline numbers. If a number starts with 07 it will be accepted as a mobile number.

looking at other threads I've tried the following but now neither the mobile or telephone field are being populated in the crm or being passed to the log file?

```
 function process_contact_form_data( $contact_form ) {
     $title = $contact_form->title;
     $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

     if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
     }


    if ( 'Quote Form_Contact' || 'Quote Form_Product' || 'Quote Form'  == $title ) {

      $firstName = $posted_data['user_first_name'];
      $lastName = $posted_data['user_last_name'];
      $email= $posted_data['your-email'];
      $phone = $posted_data['your-number'];
      $message = $posted_data['your-message'];
      $bp = $posted_data['BP'][0];

      $phone = $pattern;    
      $pattern = "/^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/";
      $match = preg_match($pattern,$phone);
      if ($match != false) {$mobile = $phone;} else {$mobile= '';};
    }

    $error = false;
    try
    {
    $relationshipId =   postRelationship($firstName,$lastName,$email,$phone,$bp);
    $opportunityId = postOpportunity($relationshipId,$message);
    postOpportunityNote($relationshipId,$opportunityId,$message);
      //  postTask($relationshipId);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
      $error=true;
    }
    if($error || !isset($relationshipId) || !isset($opportunityId) || $relationshipId <= 0 || $opportunityId <= 0)
    {
      $log->lfile(ABSPATH . 'quotevine.log');
      $log->lwrite('ERROR: With Email Address ' . $email);
      $log->lclose();
    }
 }
 add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'process_contact_form_data');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are overwriting your `$phone` variable in this line `$phone = $pattern;` with an undefined variable which will cause `$phone` to be NULL.

But after commenting out that line, the value of `$mobile` will still not be correct because  a mobile number starts with `07` and the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Mafxrt/1) matches both the landline and the mobile number, for example:

```
07123123123
+447123123123
```

What you could do is if the match succeeded, check if the string starts with `+44` to verify it is a mobile number.
[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns `false` if an error occurred but I think you want to verify if the match is correct.

```
$phone = "+447123123123";
$pattern = "/^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/";
$mobile= '';

if (preg_match($pattern,$phone) && 0 === strpos($phone, '07')) {
    $mobile = $phone;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. telephone is now being entered but mobile is still not returning a value?

Comment: Did you check in the [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/Mafxrt/1) if the phonenumber you entered matches? Can you check if you get in the if statement and var_dump `$mobile`?

Comment: It validates fine in the regex tester. Not sure how best to var_dump the `$mobile` as I've only got a live instance to work on.

Comment: In your code above you are not yet doing anything with `$mobile`, but you use `$phone` in `postRelationship`. Did you update your code to do something with `$mobile?`

Comment: Id missed adding `$mobile` into an arg in the code that submits data to the CRM (schoolboy error). All works perfectly now. Thank you once again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the phone with an undefined variable.

```
  // Phone is now a phone number I assume
  $phone = $posted_data['your-number'];
  $message = $posted_data['your-message'];
  $bp = $posted_data['BP'][0];

  // $pattern is as far as I can see undefined
  // $phone =NULL
  $phone = $pattern;    
  // You set pattern
  $pattern = "/^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/";
  // Here you regex if the pattern matches NULL which it does not.
  $match = preg_match($pattern,$phone);
```